# mvc razor linq statement which is including firstordefault and where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to know if its possible to fix this statement:

```
@Model.OrdinalDataList.Where(s =>s.CompetitorId == c.Id).Select(x => x.TotalScore).FirstOrDefault()
```

For example, I have a list of 50 objects, and each 5 objects have the same ID.

I want to get the TotalScore value from one of them from each 5 objects that have the same value for TotalScore for each ID.

Using FirstOrDefault gives me the first value in the collection no matter what the ID of the competitor is.

So my question is, what am I missing here to make this statement work correctly.

Comment: I don't understand this --> 'I want to get the TotalScore value from one of them from each 5 objects are having the same value for TotalScore for each ID.'

Comment: So... you want to go from a collection of 50 objects to a collection of 10 objects, assuming that there are 10 sets of 5 objects with the same ID? Is the TotalScore in each set of 5 different or the same?  Please show an example data set to help us understand.

Comment: @TLS yes like each 5 objects are having same id and same totalscore. I want to get the totalscore based on the competitor id thx

Comment: I'm also confused, do you want the Sum(TotalScore), or a collection of TotalScore for each competitor?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, I think what you want is `Distinct` instead of the `Where` and the `Select` and no `FirstOrDefault` on the end.

```
@Model.OrdinalDataList.Distinct().Select(x => x.TotalScore)
```

NOTE:  untested!

If that doesn't work because there are more properties in the objects, then you might need to do a `Select` before the `Distinct` to get a projection of just the `ID` and `TotalScore` properties and then do the final `Select` to get just the `TotalScore`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why you have the same data in your list 5 times, but this should get the TotalScore of the first item in the list with the matching competitor ID:

```
var score = @Model.OrdinalDataList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CompetitorId == c.Id).TotalScore;
```